# Why filtering this IEnumerable throws an NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ienumerable

I have a peculiar problem I do not seem to solve. I am very sure this error comes from my lack of a deep understanding of how LINQ query work

- The following service returns a list of products and works fine (and nothing is null)

  `IEnumerable<Product> products = await _productRepository.GetProductList();`

  I have tested the returned products and none of their properties (e.g., Name, Price, Description) are null. In fact, I can display them on a table.
- However, if I try to filter the returned products, I get an `NullReferenceException`

`IEnumerable<Product> products =products.Where(x=>x.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(keyword.ToLower())).ToList();`

The above code throws a `NullReferenceException` even though I have checked the property `Name` is not null (in fact, nothing is null)

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: `var lst = products.Where(x=> x?.Name != null && keyword != null).Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(keyword.ToLower())).ToList();` This is extremely inefficient, but use that line and see if you still get the exception. If it doesn't then either `keyword` is null, or `x.Name` is null somewhere. If you are still getting the exception, then `products` is null.

Comment: This may occur due to an error inside GetProductList, as the IEnumerable is not evaluated until ToList is called

Comment: One obvious reason is that `keyword` is null. Failing that, a `NullReferenceException` in this code likely means that you a fetching the entire table and filtering on the client, which in turn means you are using an outdated version of EF where this happens silently (newer versions raise an exception if the filter cannot be translated to SQL), so remove that `ToLower()` so that the database decides case sensitivity.

Comment: Thanks, everyone for the comments. `keyword is not null. I will investigate @JonasHøgh's suggestions and see if this fix the problem

Comment: Why do you have a repository that returns IEnumerable and filtering after retrieval?  Just ask EF to filter the data on the server side.

Comment: It's very inefficient to get `products` as `IEnumerable` and then filter. The filter isn't executed by the database which it would when filtering `GetProductList()` -- if that 's `IQueryable`.

Answer (score 1):

This code would not compile:

```
IEnumerable<Product> products = await _productRepository.GetProductList();
IEnumerable<Product> products = products.Where(x=>x.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(keyword.ToLower())).ToList();
```

So you would need to be doing something a bit different to what your example states:

If you have something like:

```
IEnumerable<Product> products = await _productRepository.GetProductList()
    .Where(x=>x.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(keyword.ToLower()))
    .ToListAsync();
```

... then this should compile. A `NullReferenceException` from this statement would likely be from `keyword` being null.

As mentioned in the above comments, this is a very poor performing way to fetch back data. The issue is that if your repository returns `IEnumerable` it will be loading ***ALL*** products into memory, only to have your consuming code filter down to a few.

If you are employing unit testing, the repository pattern I would recommend is to have the repositories return `IQueryable<TEntity>` rather than `IEnumerable<TEntity>` so that your consuming code can apply things like filtering:

The consuming statement would be identical:

```
IEnumerable<Product> products = await _productRepository.GetProductList()
    .Where(x=>x.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(keyword.ToLower()))
    .ToListAsync();
```

... except this way the `Where` condition will be applied through to the SQL that EF generates leading to a far more efficient query. This requires ensuring that the DbContext instance is scoped to cover both the caller and the repository. (I.e. provided through dependency injection and scoped to the life of the web request for example)

If you aren't using unit testing then the Repository pattern doesn't add anything and it would be more efficient to just utilize the DbContext directly to produce efficient queries.

Comment: If only OP would reveal the returned type of `GetProductList()`... Maybe worth mentioning that *if* it's `IQueryable` it's probably not necessary to use `ToLower` at all because the database collation determines the comparison and often defaults to case insensitive.

Comment: Yeah, most repository implementations I come across return back `List<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`, that the implementation he's calling is `async` would most certainly fit that pattern. The case sensitivity would depend on the database collation, which hasn't been disclosed either. A Null name is possible though he implies the data comes back.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you want to resolve cases that are null but my guess in your case you can assume it doesn't start with the keyword. **Null conditional Operator paired with null coalesce** is your best bet. Honestly you should always anticipate null references and know how you want to handle them. I assume keyword is a constant but if it is not that should also be null checked

```
products = products
    .Where(x => x?.Name?.ToLower().StartsWith(keyword.ToLower()) ?? false)
    .ToList();
```